# How do you assign a row to a Panda data frame while iterating?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, variable-assignment

```
import reverse_geocoder as rg
import pandas as pd
for i in range(len(df_train)) : 
    coordinate = (df_train.loc[i, "Lat"], df_train.loc[i, "Long_"]) 
    geo_dict=rg.get(coordinate)
    geo_code.loc[i,:]=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(geo_dict,orient='index').T
  # geo_code=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(geo_dict,orient='index').T
    print (geo_code)
```

I'd like to finish with geo_code DF continuing one row from each reverse geocode lookup. My assignment

```
geo_code.loc[i,:]
```

does not work.

Comment: Please post a sample of `df_train` not as an image, its impossible to help without looking at the data

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here`import reverse_geocoder as rg
import pandas as pd
geo_code=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df_train)) : 
    coordinate = (df_train.loc[i, "Lat"], df_train.loc[i, "Long_"]) 
    geo_dict=rg.get(coordinate)  
    geo_code=geo_code.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(geo_dict,orient='index').T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a DataFrame index before creating a data frame

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame({"Lat": [36.778259,28.644800],"Long_":[-119.417931,77.216721]})
for i in range(len(df_train)):
    coordinate = (df_train.loc[i, "Lat"], df_train.loc[i, "Long_"])
    geo_dict=rg.get(coordinate)
    value_array = np.array([[el] for el in geo_dict.values()]).reshape(1,-1)
    if i == 0:
        geo_code = pd.DataFrame(value_array, columns=geo_dict.keys())
    else:
        d1 = pd.DataFrame(value_array, columns=geo_dict.keys())
        geo_code = pd.concat([geo_code, d1], ignore_index=True)
```

print(geo_code)

[image]